# Linq query is causing unusual code behavior

Tags: linq, datatable

Framework 4.6, c#. And I hope I can explain this well.

Here's how our vendor lets us implement custom business rules into their .net app:

We can extend the app with our own custom classes.
We code business rules as methods in those classes.
Each method has its name in a record in a sql server table, with a column called Active.
 
If Active=1 the name of the function to execute is loaded into an array/list in vendor code, it then cycles through the array and calls each our of custom methods.

I need to create a custom method to call a vendor method that returns an object (but is really a DataTable) that I can analyze.

Here's the beginning and end of the vendor method:

```
    private object GetSomeData(ArrayList pParam)
    {
        DataTable rval = new DataTable("aggTable");
        rval.Columns.Add("KeyString", typeof(string));
        rval.Columns.Add("RequestType", typeof(string));
        rval.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(string));
        ...
        ...
        //Load data
        ...
        ...
        return rval;
    }
```

In my custom method, I want to cycle through the data that's returned. I need to find at least one record that meets a certain conditon - a Status of EC and a RequestType of Prospect.

My issue is that in my custom method I wrote this code:

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)(CallVendorFunction["GetSomeData"](null));
if (dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r => (r.Field<String>("Status") == "EC") && (r.Field<String>("RequestType") == "Prospect")).Count() > 0)
   {
       //Do some trivial stuff
   }
```

The code is going crazy at the LINQ code in the if statement.

The app compiles totally fine and seemingly runs totally fine. But whether the database record for my method has Active=0 or Active=1 doesn't matter - just having that Linq code causes no custom methods to be called. Nothing crashes, but nothing happens.

I narrowed it down to that Linq line by brute force, and if I replace the if statement with something as lame as *if (true)*, all is good.

I could replace the Linq line with a basic for loop against each row, but what is wrong with the code in the Linq line???

Comment: Break it into steps and debug. `var test = dt.AsEnumerable()` Does this have expected data? Then craft an `Any()` query: `if (dt.AsEnumerable().Any(r => r.Field<string>("Status") == "EC" && r.Field<string>("RequestType") == "Prospect"))`

Comment: Will try, thanks. Also I updated the code. I noticed my code had *Field<string>* when it should have been *Field<String>*. I thought that was the issue but it was not.

Comment: @Steve. Interesting, same crazy behavior when I simply have the line ````EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> dre = dt.AsEnumerable()````. This is hurting my head.

Comment: Try going to a List: List<DataRow> list = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList();

Comment: Note in C# that `String` (the .Net class) and `string` (the C# type) are synonyms.

Comment: "The code is going crazy at the LINQ code in the if statement." -- what does this mean, exactly? What is the behavior?

Comment: @NetMage  - the behavior is that none of the custom code is called in the custom class with that Linq line present. Project builds fine, and at run time no errors are thrown.

Comment: @Steve, I tried the List<DataRow>, same issue - no code executes. I will keep plugging away.

Comment: "Code going crazy" implies an error, hangup, etc. If it just skips the block it is most likely returning a false condition - move that condition to a separate line to test (`var hasMatch = dt.AsEnumerable().Where...)`. You also mention an Active flag in your question, but I see no reference to that? The very first step would be does `dt` have an unfiltered datatable with data that meets your criteria.